# Guidance On Model Design With Navigation Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions, ef-code-first

I'm using MVC 4 Code First With EF 5 and trying to normalize some data. I'll start off with three entities and give an example of my two different scenarios...

User Model

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string PseudoName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

   // Other account related properties....

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Address Model

```
public class Address
{
    public int UserLocationId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    // Address properties
}
```

Profile Model

```
public class Profile
{
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    // Specific details about the user...
}
```

I'm not too familiar with how EF handles transactions. Normally I'd make a DB like this and fire up a transaction to ensure that when the user gets created that I can create a User, Profile and Address record on the creation of a user. Doing it this way with EF I have to add the user and save it then retrieve the userId from the newly generated user and then call two more inserts and add the keys to the Address/Profile models and save them. I feel weary of doing it this way since if something fails along the way then the user file will not be complete. Now here's how I had originally did it but not sure if this is acceptable on the DB side but seems to work ok so far, just need a second opinion.

The second scenario basically removes the foreign keys from the Address and Profile models and what I do is create my User object with the context and just create a new Profile/Address property within the User object and just insert and save the object to the DB. What happens on the DB side is it creates a new Profile/Address without any FKs but adds FKs in the User table as Profile_ProfileId, Address_AddressId.

Does the second option make more sense to do over the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is smart enough to handle insertion of multiple related entities in a single transaction.

```
var user = new User { };
user.Profile = new Profile { };
user.Address = new Address { };
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It will figure out the insertion order of the entities and update the properties with database generated PK values.

Comment: Yeah if I do it in a particular way like you have listed there. I figured out how to make the FKs in the Navigation Properties tables rather than the main class's tables so it works out great now this way.